# Поиск на лету со стороны верстки.

Tags: jquery, html, javascript, css

Всем привет. Ребята, меня видимо чуток замкнуло) В общем если на этом [сайте](http://www.vashmagazin.by/) начать вводить текст в поиск (Bosch, например) снизу появляется блок, предлагающий результаты поиска. Как это реализовано? Интересует клиентская часть

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Такую штуку можно реализовать на **jQuery** и **php+MySQL**. Работает все очень просто, мы через *jQuery* отправляем запрос, через *php* его обрабатываем и получаем ответ.

Примерно можно сделать это так:

**html:**

*Создаем строку ввода и вывода ответа*

`<input type='text' name='text' id='text'> <div id='mess'></div>`

**jQuery:**

`$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#text').keyup(function(){
    $.post('php_check.php',{name: $('#text').val()}, function(data){
      $('#mess').text(data);   
    });
  });
});`

**php:**

*Обрабатываем запрос*

`<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$row = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE name='$name'"));
echo $row['name'];
?>`

Ну примерно так, код еще нужно модернизировать, но технология такая :)

Answer (score 2):

Судя по подключённым скриптам и стилям, это [jQuery Autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/).